# Next.js redirect from an API route

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I am building a back-office app that requires users to sign in.
I have 2 external APIs:

- API A : to manage user accounts and sessions
- API B : to perform CRUD actions on another database (unrelated to users database)

The problem is that I don't want users to be able to perform calls to API B if their session is not valid. So I added some API endpoints in Next (under `pages/api`) that do the following actions:

1. verifying the validity of the session against API A
2. if session is valid: continue to step 3, if not: redirect to page `/login`
3. make the call to API B

Everything works fine if the session is valid but it fails if the session is not valid.

I have tried

```
res.redirect(307, '/login').end()
```

and

```
res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/login' }).end()
```

but it didn't work. It fails even by specifying the whole path (`http://localhost:3000/login`). What I don't understand is that I am successfully redirected to my `/login` page if I make the request directly from the browser (GET `http://localhost:3000/api/data`). It doesn't work when I make the request with Axios inside a React component.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Axios will not automatically follow the redirect returned by the API. You'll need to check for the response you get, and make the redirect on the client-side based on what's returned.

Comment: To put it simply, AJAX will only relay information passed back from server. You need to handle manually what to do with that information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @juliomalves and @yqlim explained, I had to make the redirect manually based on the response of the API.

Comment: Hi @Jules, any chance you could psuedo code what you mean by manually redirect based on response? I'm in the same boat; I've authenticated and it's hit my callback api route, I've got the details I want but now am unsure how to redirect to a Page

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm in the same boat too.  Quickbooks sends the user back to my callback API after installing the app which I save the data to the database.  Once this is done I would like to redirect the user back to the app again.

Comment: Actually, nevermind.  This worked for me: res.status(200).redirect(307, "/");

Comment: Hello @ShannonCole ! Sorry for the late reply, I was not active. I'm glad your solution worked for you :)
As for me, if I remember well, in the front-end I had to redirect the user to the login page if the request (from Next, not the external API) ended with status 401 (unauthorized)

Comment: No worries!  Thanks.  I used the redirect in the api and router.push on the front end. 

Comment: @ShannonCole you do not need `.status(200)`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `.end()`. Have you tried `res.redirect(307, '/login')`?

In Next.js v12 and v13, the following works for me.

```js
// /api/example.js

const handler = async function (req, res) {
  // custom logic
  if (failed)
    return res.redirect(307, '/login')
}

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced same problem solve using below code:

Api

```
res.status(200).json({ success: "success" }) //add at last of the api to give response
```

page

```
import Router from 'next/router'
    
let res = await fetch('api', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
if (res.status == 200) {
   Router.push('/location')
}
```

Answer is correct as @Jules Grenier sayes,but provided an example

Comment: You're not redirecting from the API route and following the redirect URL, though. That's just sending a regular 200.

Answer (score 0):

The API request must be initiated by a `<form>`.

redirect will not work with `<fetch>`

Comment: links might go out of date, please edit the post and add the distilled version of what the github post is saying.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33463601)