# Next.js page redirect without any React component

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a page where the only work that needs to do is an HTTP redirect **programmatically**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/',
      permanent: false,
    },
  }
}

function Home() {
  return <></>
}

export default Home
```

Is it possible to create a page without the React component or should I use a function inside the API directory to do this job?

If yes, how can I use a function on API dir to do this?

Comment: You probably could use [redirects in next.config.js file](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects).

Comment: I need to query the database. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe if you don't have a default export in a page, next will throw an error. So yes you have to write a component and export it. You could also `return null` instead of returning a fragment. You could also use [middlewares](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to redirect. You could redirect from an api route like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678382/next-js-redirect-from-an-api-route).

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am building a URL shortener using Nextjs as a hobby project

Answer (score 0):

instead you can redirect in next.config.js by using async rewrites() i.e. giving source and destination.