How do I redirect user after succesful registration in NextJS 14?
Was trying to get familiar with nextJS 14.2.3
So I created a simple registration form, and tried to register a user. Sequelize appears to work fine, but I can't understand, how does the NextResponse.redirect() works.
This is the code of the endpoint:
    try {
        const body = await req.json();
        const salt = generateSalt();
        const hashedPassword = hashPassword(body.password, salt);
        const newUser = await User.create({
            ...body,
            password: hashedPassword,
            salt,
        });

        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return NextResponse.json({message: "internal server error"}, { status: 500 });
    }
}

It appears to successfully create a new user and send a 307 status response with redirect to homepage. But it actually does not do anything.
May it be because it's a POST request, so it responds with POST?

Your question has already been answered in this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678382/next-js-redirect-from-an-api-route
